# Burp proxy between non proxy aware device

Tags: http, proxy, man-in-the-middle, burp-suite

I want to intercept traffic between a Ethernet connected device, which is not proxy aware and modify/inject javascript. Conventionally when testing webapps I would use burp.

Can burp sit on my machine listen on one network interface and use the other network interface to forward the traffic to the desired destination? If not is there a better way to inject data into a http session?

The device under test is an embedded device which is why it isn't proxy aware.

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at burps support for [Invisible proxying](http://www.portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_options_invisible.html)?  It sounds like it would help with the test you're looking at as it's designed to let burp work with non-proxy aware clients.